# Save LESS files as CSS with Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

Microsoft recently released [Web Tools 2012.2](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/aspnet-and-web-tools-20122-release-notes-rtw). The release notes state that it supports

> LESS editing and compiler support to enable building dynamic CSS using LESS.

but when I save a LESS file, it doesn't output a corresponding CSS file like it used to with [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6). How do I get it to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the LESS Processor isn't supported in the free versions of Visual Studio. But there is a good LESS processor for free in Web Matrix (also free). Not a great solution, but it works.

Comment: I have a registered version but its still not working

Comment: Regsitered is still free version.